# Sqlite data Migration

Tags: iphone, sqlite, objective-c-2.0

What is best possible way for in-app Sqlite Data Migration. As I am new to iphone development , I created my app using Sqlite. Please help the concern

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly you want your database to migrate?

Comment: I want to update the version of my app on app store, so need to migrate the user data, as my new version could have new table in it.

Comment: Do you want to delete older tables from the previous version of app?Or you simply want that the users who are already using your app, when download new version, their data will be their with new app?

Comment: No just want to have data from the old DB to my new DB which also have some new table in it ,as the feature of the app is enhanced.

Comment: @ankit.tlp: This is what my answer does. Keeps the data from old DB intact for the users who are already using it and also includes the new changes. The changes are to be don through queries. Please refer to my answer for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a database upgrade procedure and make it execute the first time when the application starts.

So this will create a new table through a create statement when application loads for the first time.

And also it will help you save all the data that user has in his current database. This is what is most recommended as there is no additional requirement to migrate your existing database anywhere.

Also please refer to my answer in this link:

[Don't wan't to replacing the old database when app is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239088/dont-want-to-replacing-the-old-database-when-app-is-updated/7239140#7239140)

Hope this helps you.

If you need more help then please feel free to contact me.

**EDIT:**

In case when you need to make changes to an exiting table which contains some data then you need to do some steps as follows:

1) Rename the existing table

Say TableName was 'TestTable', So Rename the table to 'TestTableOld'

2) Create a new table called 'TestTable' which has the new columns you want and other altercations made.

3) Copy data from 'TestTableOld' to 'TestTable' with the query like:

Insert into TestTable('col1',col2'...'coln') Values Select col1, col2, col3,...'coln' From TestTableOld;

4) Drop the table 'TestTableOld'

Follow the above four step procedure as this would work as an alter statement and also it would preserve all your data from your original table.

Hope you get it.

Comment: Sir , IS there any working Example to do so, as i am very new to this field.

Comment: No there is a working example for this but I have implemented several places. You just need to programmatically execute Create Table  statements and other statements like Update Statements and Insert Statements under the upgrade procedure just the same way as you execute your select statement queries in the database .

Comment: Yes I find your link helpful , any link for the Working example ?

Comment: Nope I have implemented it in many of my projects but there is no tutorial link I have for this.

Comment: That mean, if I have the database in the document directory then i'll check it for the database version and if version differ from the updated App database , then i need to programmatically make changes to my database. But if i need to make changes to a table which already have some data in it, i read from the Sqlite doc that sqlite does not support Alter table statement.

Comment: Yes Correct..I will give you a way for that. Please give me five mins

Comment: Please check the **EDIT** section of my answer. It answers to your doubt about the alter statement.

Comment: Thank you , i will try to give an hit on this. One more query i have, Currently i have no information about the DB version in my database then how do test it for the DB Version during an update to App.

Comment: You are welcome :). For this version you can do it with a NSUserDefaults flag Value instead of Version Number. But Include a Versions table in this version upgrade as it can e helpful for future use.

Comment: I am trying to use user_version from the DB to check the database version and for my new DB version after making changes to my OLD DB,i am trying to update the user_version by usual prepare statement in sqlite, but due to some reson it fails, can u help me in this regard.

Comment: No that is not the way you should do. You need to create a Table called "Versions" and You need to provide your app version number in a table. Then you can do it.

Comment: sir, i am using user_version ,which i found through some search [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2357509/985114) for the DB version , as my first DB has no table for DB version. Further I think the one suggested by you is the best option ,but for now , what i tried is as above.

Comment: In order to migrate legacy data, every time app upgrades and if there are any table schema changes, we need to write new sql scripts/statements ? So there cannot be common script to migrate data I suppose. Thanks